# Arduino shield, SD card Data logge, why are my SD cards dying?

Tags: arduino, sd-card

I'm having a real anoying problem that I carnt seem to find a solution on.

I have created a simple arduino code for sweeping a curve on 2 analog pin, controlled by a DAC unit. The sweeps are being done in real time, ones a second, and is stored on a SD card in files split into hours.

My problem is that my SPI interface on the SD cards stop responding during continues used. 
I use the following arduino mega shield 
http://pcb.daince.net/doku.php?id=data_logger
and a "Kingston MicroSDHC 4GB Secure Digital Card, 66X" for storage

I ran the the following code for 3 days and when I came back the SPI was none responding (I have done 1 hours tests before with no problem, and I have checked that the system changes files correctly)

```
#include "SPI.h"
#include <SD.h>
#include "Wire.h"

//Static definitions 
#define ADG509_A0_pin          39
#define ADG509_A1_pin          38
#define SS_DAC_pin             53
#define voltage_analog_pin     11
#define current_analog_pin     12
#define led                    13
#define DS1307_ADDRESS         0x68
#define chip_select            53

//Adjustable definitions 
#define ADC_to_voltage         1/213 // the value for converting the arduino ADC to voltage
#define number_of_samples      100   //number of measurements, should be able to be divided by 4 without giving decimals
#define time_per_data_set      500   //the delay between datasets in milisecondss, note the the "delay = system_computation_time + time_per_data_set"   
#define current_gain_ratio     2     //the realtion between the voltage level on the pin and current on from the solar pannel
#define voltage_gain_ratio     10  //the realtion between the voltage level on the pin and the voltage level from the solar panel
#define number_samples_per_measurement    5   //the number of ADC readings used to make an average of each measuring point, note this number greatly effects sweeping time
#define delay_per_measurement    1



void set_DAC(float value);           // gets an input between 0.0 and 5.0 and sets the voltage to the value
void write_measurement_to_SD(float current, float voltage, int number);  //writes the numbers to the SD card if initialized
void write_to_file();                //check is a new SD card file should be created and makes it ef nessesary. Also handles the data writing to the file
void get_time();                     //Get the current time of the system, and store them in global variables
int bcdToDec(byte val);              //Converts bytes to decimals numbers 
char intToChar(int val, int number); //Converts integers to chars, only exept up to 2 dicimals

word output_word_for_DAC = 0;        //used to type cast input of set_DAC to word before usage
byte data = 0;                       //temp variable need for DAC, it is the byte send over the communication
float volt;                          //stores a temporary voltage measurement
float current;                       //stores a temporary current measurement
float current_level;                 //stores the short curciut current level, it is used to find the optimal placement for measuring points
char filename[13] = "F0000000.txt";  //stores the current active filename for writing on the SD card
File dataFile;                       //the current version of the datafile on the SD card
int years, months, monthsDay, weekDay, hours, minute, seconds; //global varibles used to store the last time reading
float current_array[number_of_samples]; //used to store all current measurements points during sweep
float voltage_array[number_of_samples]; //used to store all voltage measurements points during sweep
int typecast_int;                    // used for typecasting float to int 
int last_measurement_time;
int is_SDcard_there;

void setup() {   
  pinMode(ADG509_A0_pin, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(ADG509_A1_pin, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(SS_DAC_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT); 

  digitalWrite(led, LOW);  
  digitalWrite(ADG509_A1_pin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ADG509_A0_pin, LOW);

  SPI.begin(); // start up the SPI bus
  SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);

  Wire.begin();
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {;}
  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
  if (!SD.begin(chip_select)) {
    Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
    is_SDcard_there = 0;
    return;+
  }
  Serial.println("card initialized.");
  is_SDcard_there = 1;
}

void loop() {
  //finding the shortcurcuit current of the solar panel
  get_time();
  last_measurement_time = seconds;
  set_DAC(5); //open fet
  delayMicroseconds(1000);
  current_level = analogRead(current_analog_pin);
  for(float counter2 = 0; counter2 < 10; counter2++){
    current_level += analogRead(current_analog_pin);
  }
  current_level = (current_level/10)* 1.1 * ADC_to_voltage;
  //fully opening the fet to insure that the solar pannel is stable at max voltage before beginning the sweep
  set_DAC(0); //ground fet
  delayMicroseconds(10000);  

  if(is_SDcard_there == 1){
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH); 
  } 

  //sweeping the first 80% current on the curve with 25% of the measuring points 
  //note no calculations should be put in here, since it slow the sweep down  
  for(float counter = 0; counter < number_of_samples * 0.25; counter++){ 
    set_DAC((counter*current_level * 0.80) / (number_of_samples * 0.25));
    delayMicroseconds(200);  
    current = analogRead(current_analog_pin);
    volt = analogRead(voltage_analog_pin);
    for(float counter2 = 0; counter2 < number_samples_per_measurement - 1; counter2++){
      current += analogRead(current_analog_pin);
      volt += analogRead(voltage_analog_pin);
    }
    current = current / number_samples_per_measurement;
    volt = volt / number_samples_per_measurement;
    typecast_int = counter;
    current_array[typecast_int] = current;
    voltage_array[typecast_int] = volt;
  }

  //sweeping the last 20% current on the curve with 75% of the measuring points 
  //note no calculations should be put in here, since it slow the sweep down  
  for(float counter = 0; counter < number_of_samples * 0.75; counter++){ 
    set_DAC(current_level * 0.80 + (counter*current_level * 0.20) / (number_of_samples * 0.75));
    delayMicroseconds(200);  
    current = analogRead(current_analog_pin);
    volt = analogRead(voltage_analog_pin);
    for(float counter2 = 0; counter2 < number_samples_per_measurement - 1; counter2++){
      current += analogRead(current_analog_pin);
      volt += analogRead(voltage_analog_pin);
    }
    current = current / number_samples_per_measurement;
    volt = volt / number_samples_per_measurement;
    typecast_int = counter + number_of_samples * 0.25;
    current_array[typecast_int] = current;
    voltage_array[typecast_int] = volt;
  }

  set_DAC(5); //sets DAC high to prepare for next short curcuit measurement 
  digitalWrite(led, LOW); 

  //converting data to desired values and writing them to the file
  String to_write = "";
  int check;
  char buffer[20];
  to_write = "0,0,-2";
  to_write += '\r';
  to_write += '\n';
  to_write += "0,";
  to_write += intToChar(minute,0);
  to_write += intToChar(minute,1);
  to_write += intToChar(seconds,0);
  to_write += intToChar(seconds,1);
  to_write += ",-1";
  to_write += '\r';
  to_write += '\n';

  for(int counter = 0; counter < number_of_samples-1; counter++){
    to_write += dtostrf(current_array[counter] = current_array[counter] * ADC_to_voltage * current_gain_ratio, 0, 2, buffer);
    to_write += ",";
    to_write += dtostrf(voltage_array[counter] = voltage_array[counter] * ADC_to_voltage * voltage_gain_ratio, 0, 2, buffer);
    to_write += ",";
    to_write += counter;
    to_write += '\r';
    to_write += '\n';
  }
  to_write += dtostrf(current_array[99] = current_array[99] * ADC_to_voltage * current_gain_ratio, 0, 2, buffer);
  to_write += ",";
  to_write += dtostrf(voltage_array[99] = voltage_array[99] * ADC_to_voltage * voltage_gain_ratio, 0, 2, buffer);
  to_write += ",99";
  Serial.println(to_write);  //should only be used for debugging since it slow down the system to much

  compute_filename(); //initialize a new filename if needed

  check = 0;
  while(check == 0 && is_SDcard_there == 1){
    dataFile = SD.open(filename,FILE_WRITE);
    check = dataFile.println(to_write);
    if (dataFile){
      dataFile.close();
    }
  } 

  //wait for next seconds      
while(last_measurement_time + delay_per_measurement > seconds){
    get_time(); 
    if(seconds < last_measurement_time){seconds = seconds + 60;}
  }
}

// gets an input between 0.0 and 5.0 and sets the voltage to the value
void set_DAC(float value){
  if(value <= 5){
    value = value*819;    
    int conveter = value;
    output_word_for_DAC = conveter;
    digitalWrite(SS_DAC_pin, LOW);
    data = highByte(output_word_for_DAC);
    data = 0b00001111 & data;
    data = 0b00110000 | data;
    SPI.transfer(data);
    data = lowByte(output_word_for_DAC);
    SPI.transfer(data);
    digitalWrite(SS_DAC_pin, HIGH);
  }
}

//writes the numbers to the SD card if initialized
void write_measurement_to_SD(float current, float voltage, int number){
  dataFile = SD.open(filename,FILE_WRITE);
  dataFile.print(current);
  dataFile.print(',');
  dataFile.print(voltage);
  dataFile.print(',');
  dataFile.print(number);   
  dataFile.println(';');  
  if (dataFile){
    dataFile.close();
  }
}

//Converts bytes to decimals numbers 
int bcdToDec(byte val){
   return ( (val/16*10) + (val%16) );
} 

//Converts integers to chars, only exept up to 2 dicimals
char intToChar(int val, int number){  // note it only take ints with 2 digits
  String tempString = "";
  char returnValue[3];
  if(val < 10){
    tempString += 0;
  }
  tempString += val;
  tempString.toCharArray(returnValue,3);
  return returnValue[number];
}

//Get the current time of the system, and store them in global variables
void get_time(){
   Wire.beginTransmission(DS1307_ADDRESS);
   byte zero = 0x00;
   Wire.write(zero);
   Wire.endTransmission();
   Wire.requestFrom(DS1307_ADDRESS, 7);
   seconds = bcdToDec(Wire.read());
   minute = bcdToDec(Wire.read());
   hours = bcdToDec(Wire.read() & 0b111111); //24 hours time
   weekDay = bcdToDec(Wire.read()); //0-6 -> sunday - Saturday
   monthsDay = bcdToDec(Wire.read());
   months = bcdToDec(Wire.read());
   years = bcdToDec(Wire.read());
}

//check if the system need a new filename
void compute_filename(){
  get_time();
  filename[1] = intToChar(years,1);
  filename[2] = intToChar(months,0);
  filename[3] = intToChar(months,1);
  filename[4] = intToChar(monthsDay,0);
  filename[5] = intToChar(monthsDay,1);
  filename[6] = intToChar(hours,0);
  filename[7] = intToChar(hours,1);
  if (dataFile){
    dataFile.close();
  }  
}
```

I know that this is a big code dump and I'm sorry for that, but I carnt realy cut it down when I have no idea what is killing my SD cards.

Any help on the matter is appreciated
and any ideas on what I can test to isolate or locate the error is also welcome

Comment: Clear up the question.  You say the cards "stop responding" and also "killing".  These are very different problems, one temporary, one permanent.  Does the SD card work if you simply power cycle and restart?  Or is the SD card killed and doesn't work even on a computer?

Answer (score 1):

there can be 2 possible errors:

1 resource leak

2 RAM overflow

for 1 you can put some code that write on serial RAM usage evry loop(), if that number grow, some library (as you aren't allocating memory with alloc() )is broken. For 2, don't build up to_write, but use directly Serial.println(), alyas try to use array/string wicth use LESS than 100 byte or you might have problem (String dinamically allocate space, and that allocation can fail.. silently. then bad things appen)

Answer (score 1):

I've done a lot of work with SD cards during the past 10 years and I've noticed that the SD card is very easily bricked into a non-responsive mode *if it receives garbage in the CMD line*. It seems that at least some kind of garbage is interpreted as a command to set the card password, thus locking the card. It has happened to me at least 10 times in as many years when I've been working with SD library code or new hardware designs, so it looks to me that it must be some bit patterns which is easily generated somehow.

I've been able to rescue the (micro)SD cards by putting them into my old Symbian phone which immediately recognizes that the card is locked and offers to reformat the card and reset the password. You might try the same with your SD card, to see if your problem is the same I've experienced. I remember vaguely that some cheap Canon camera was also able to rescue some card in a similar way.